# Why are my JQuery Modal boxes not in there default position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Until recently any modal box I displayed was dead center in the page. Which I assume is the default and is what I wanted.

Recently some change I made someplace in my code is causing the modal to open on the left bottom of the page, just poking up above the bottom of the screen.

I've explored all the code I've changed in the past weeks and can't find it. I also had updated the 'jquery.modal.min.css' file to the current version v0.9.1 so replaced that with the previous version. But that didn't fix it either.

I'm the first to admit I do not understand how to use the 'Web Inspector' effectively. If this is how I can track down the issue please be specific on its use.

Comment: I fell back to the previous version of jquery.modal.min.css and everything went back the way it should. I don't pretend to know what the difference is between the two versions so I'll just stick with the one that works.

Answer (score 0):

well, you need to provide a fiddle so we can see any example of your code. That been said:

- do you use GIT( you might be able to version back ALL files that might have been touched, keep in mind any new changes are gone).
- are you the only Developer working on this? is there another developer, who could have added something locally with a !important? May be someone forgot to open or close a bracket, in your css/html/structure

my 2 cents

Comment: #adnan_tariq I'm the only developer and I do not (currently) use GIT. That is another tool I hope to employ in the not too distant future.

Comment: I've had this kind of response before while asking a question but I really don't know how to do what you ask. My code is almost 5000 lines, across 20+ files, I'm never sure how to break out the part that is giving me issues. Is there a tutorial here someplace that would tell me how to do that? I'm quite serious, I'd really like to know.